# Ingesting data from multiple kafka topics into single datasource in druid

Tags: druid

Is is possible to ingest data from multiple kafka topics into a single datasource in druid ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Using **Batch ingestion** you can do it easily. Just dump your data from both kafka topic at same location and batch ingest from that location.

Using **Realtime ingestion** you would have to setup two different realtime nodes/jobs which will consume from two different topics but write to same datasource. Here you might need to Rebuild Segments (Reindexing) if your query performance is low. Because both realtime nodes/jobs will create separate segments for same time interval which should ideally have been one segment if it was one job. So running reindexing will combine those segments and improve you query performance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is is possible with druid-kafka-indexing that is supported out of the box with druid ?